# navigating and access directory in python

Tags: python, directory, path

python script
i am in the root of directory.
E:
i want to go into next directory and sub directory a with a input"directory name"

1. like first go into E:\zimi
2. and then into E:\zimi\files
   then apply operation in current directory of E:\zimi\files

navigate.py first_directory_name second_directory_name
and do rest of operation that is already done
directory name given as input.
sub directory name is also given as name. after navigating into directory

Comment: use `os.chdir()`

Comment: to use os.chdir() next directory path is necessary which is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Would os.walk() be the answer you're looking for?

i.e. assuming you're already in e:\

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
     <your code here>
```

This would traverse the directories in e:

if you wish to limit only to zimi, just:

```
os.chdir("zimi")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    <your code here>
```